# how do I make my player collide with a platform pygame

Tags: python, pygame

How do I make my player collide with my platform?

I know how to make a player move, jump and how to add walls. I also know how to make a image for my player, how to make shapes and most of the basics of python and stuff. I am learning python, and I am new to pygame.

Here is my player code:

```
class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.ss1 = pygame.image.load("G5.png")
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.ss1,self.rect)
```

And here is my full code:

````
import pygame
pygame.init()

#this is screem height
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

#know we put screem name
pygame.display.set_caption("Noobs first Game")

#player class
class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.ss1 = pygame.image.load("G5.png")
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.ss1,self.rect)

class enemy:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft=(self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


#player and enemy
white = (255,255,255)
player1 = player(0,400,60,60,white)

red = (255,48,48)
enemy1 = enemy(100,100,60,20,red)

#window
def redrawwindow():
    window.fill((0,0,0))

#player draw
    player1.draw()
    enemy1.draw()

fps = (30)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False


    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a]and player1.x > player1.speed:
        player1.x -= player1.speed

    if keys[pygame.K_d]and player1.x <500 - player1.height - player1.speed:
        player1.x += player1.speed

    if keys[pygame.K_w]and player1.y > player1.speed:
        player1.y -= player1.speed

    if keys[pygame.K_s]and player1.y <500 - player1.width - player1.speed:
        player1.y += player1.speed

    if not(player1.isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            player1.isJump = True

    else:
        if player1.JumpCount >= -10:
            player1.y -= (player1.JumpCount*abs(player1.JumpCount))*0.5
            player1.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            player1.isJump = False
            player1.JumpCount = 10




            
    redrawwindow()
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()



```
````

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question, but you might find using a [physics engine](https://www.pygame.org/project-Pygame+Physics+Engine-2836-.html) useful

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to stack overflow. Your first question is good because you gave detail, code, and were specific with question. Just try to fix your grammar and punctuation to make it a little bit easier to read.

As far as your problem goes, you want to check if the player collided with

`if player.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect):`

And then move them accordingly. For example, check the velocity and move them in the opposite direction by a small amount.